# Searching RL algorithm for specific problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have an agent which should react to different inputs I give it. Let 'A->B' stand for the agent's reaction B to an input A.

I want my agent to learn to react differently depending on the history of inputs.
For example, let each 'episode' consists of: 1. Me giving an input. 2. Agent reacting. 3. Me giving another input. 4. Agent Reacting. 5. End of episode.

If there are two possible inputs i1 and i2, and two possible actions a1 and a2, I want my agent to react as follows in all possible episodes (values not so important):
i1->a2, i1->a1; i1->a2, i2->a1; i2->a2, i1->a2; i2->a2, i2->a1;

i.e. I want my agent to react differently to an input in the second step depending on the inputs of both the first and second step.

Question: What would be an appropriate RL algorithm to learn this? In the beginning I wanted to use Q-Learning, but the problem is that my state transitions do not depend on the agent's action. I.e. if it reacts with a1 to i1, the agent doesn't at that point know whether the next 'state' will be i1 or i2.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One assumption of classical RL is that the problem can be modeled as an MDP. The Markovian property says that you do not need to know the history of past transitions to perform optimally. You task violates this assumption. I would check POMDP algorithms for your problem, but I am not very familiar with them, so I cannot suggest any.

Comment: @Simon Alright, thanks for the tip